# Calculate price from command line program

Tags: javascript, node.js

I found a very interesting exercise that asks to write a command line program, which calculates the total price of an order, where:

**1**. The total amount to be paid is the *sum* of the *price* of each product in the order *multiplied* by the *quantity* of each item in the order

**2**. Prices on the csv file do not include VAT

**3**. The total amount to be paid must include VAT at the fixed rate of 23%

**4**. If a product is out of stock, the program must end with error code 1 and display a message.

With this, there is a csv file with the following data:

```
P1,5,1000.00
P2,8,250.00
P3,15,125.00
P4,10,250.00
P5,2,2500.00
```

And the program must run from the command line with the following arguments:

Example: **$ CalculateOrder Catalog.txt P4 6 P10 5 P12 1**

**Total: 4151,25**

This is what I have at the moment:

```
var program = require('commander');
const csv = require('csv');
const fs = require('fs');

program
    .version('1.0.0')
    .option('-l, --list [list]', 'list of order prices in sample.catalog.csv')
    .parse(process.argv)

console.log("hello world")
console.log("list of order prices", program.list);

/* 
    To read csv file and print the data to the console:
    [node orderPrice --list input/sample.catalog.csv]
*/

let parse = csv.parse;
let stream = fs.createReadStream(program.list)
    .pipe(parse({ delimiter: ',' }));

stream
    .on('data', function (data) {
        let product = data[0];
        let quantity = data[1];
        let price = data[2];
        console.log(product, quantity, price);
    });
```

Through the command line I can see all the data inside the csv file, but I don't know what to do next besides the javascript function needed to calculate the price.

I'm a node.js newbie and I appreciate all your help.
Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at this [tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-an-interactive-command-line-application-with-nodejs). It will help you code it on your own and you'll learn as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The total amount to be paid is the sum of the price of each product in the order multiplied by the quantity of each item in the order

You need a global variable first for counting the total:

```
 var total = 0;
```

Them whenever a new row arrives, calculate the price and add it to total:

```
 total += price * quantity;
```

Then when the stream is done, just log the total:

```
 stream.on("finish", function() {
   console.log("Total price:", total);
 });
```

> The total amount to be paid must include VAT at the fixed rate of 23%

Thats just some multiplication at the end.

> If a product is out of stock, the program must end with error code 1 and display a message.

In that case, you should *destroy* the stream:

```
   if(quantity > 20) {
     stream.destroy(new Error("Quantity exceeds stored amounts"));
   }
```

Then you can listen to errors on the stream and act accordingly:

```
  stream.on("error", function(error) {
    console.error("The following error occured:", error);
  });
```

Through this, the "finish" event won't be triggered and the total is not displayed.

Comment: I updated the code from the question with your solution. @Jonas W

Comment: @RCohen please don't edit in an answer into the question, that will confuse other visitors ... And please read my answer more carefully ...

Comment: I'm so sorry! @Jonas W

Comment: @RCohen no worries

Comment: I understand all the logic ou explained, but there are some things confusing in code. The order of my code is not accurate? @Jonas W

Comment: @RCohen just try to run it, the engine will tell you whats wrong.